# How to store an image of my JSP page contents to MySQL and retrieve needed

Tags: java, mysql, storage

I have a jsp page having n number of items. I want to store an image of this page's contents to the MySQL database and retrieve them when needed. How would I do this? For example, I am printing a bill in PDF format, but I am not storing the values, but when I want to see that bill, I need it back.

Comment: no need to store image in database.Instead place them in a folder and store the path in DB.

Comment: look at this post. Maybe it helps to save picture of page:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312271/javascript-how-to-save-html-rendered-on-webpage-as-image

Comment: I think the link you provided is helpful. But it's not working for me.Because I don't know how to use it correctly. Could you please help me with the full implementation of canvas in a simple way? Thanks in advance