# Download Image from an html page after added some labels by using inputs and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have added a name(text) input and a button that add to a label text from the input and I putted the label: [on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVoa0.png)

I did this with javascript dom and css conatiner for the image and label.

How can I make a download button or save this image with the label inside of it?
I mean with the content that I added to the image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18312898/1772933

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take screenshot of a div with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-with-javascript)