# HTML to Image from Google Sheets to Google Drive on Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying convert html to image and save this to Google Drive. I can't find example on this site, then I ask the question.

I forming html text on script and send this to email. It looks like this:
[HTML on Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQLM3.png)

I want convert HTML Table to image and save it to Google Drive some such construction:

```
  file[i] = DriveApp.createFile(img);
  file[i].setName(text + "_#" + (i + 1));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a rendered webpage as image with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312271/how-to-save-a-rendered-webpage-as-image-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create an HTML table for an image using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, I used Class Charts.

#### Sample script:

```js
const html = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" height="100%"><tr><th>colA</th><th>colB</th><th>colC</th></tr><tr><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td></tr><tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td></tr><tr><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td>C3</td></tr></table>';
const img = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(Charts.newDataTable().addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, '').addRow([html]).build()).setOption('allowHtml', true).setDimensions(600, 300).build().getBlob();

file[i] = DriveApp.createFile(img);
file[i].setName(text + "_#" + (i + 1));
```

- `html` is a sample HTML table. Please modify it for your HTML table. The sample HTML table is as follows.

  ```html
      <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" height="100%"><tr><th>colA</th><th>colB</th><th>colC</th></tr><tr><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td></tr><tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td></tr><tr><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td>C3</td></tr></table>
  ```
- When the above script is run, the following image is obtained.

  [image]
- In this sample script, the image size is `setDimensions(600, 300)`. So please modify this for your actual situation.
- For example, if you want to save the HTML table as a PDF file, please modify `img` as follows.

  ```
    const img = Utilities.newBlob(html, MimeType.HTML).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  ```

#### References:

- [Class Charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts)
- [newDataTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts#newdatatable)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't know that Google Apps Script makes it possible to convert

Comment: good answer I didn't know that.  I'm going to come back here and work on this.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe somebody know: how I can save image with color fill some cells?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that the background color in the HTML data cannot be used in this method while the font color can be used. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your comment. This is a workaround using Class Charts using only Google Apps Script. Unfortunately, it seems that the background color cannot be used in this method.